# Intel will soon be sponsoring AI

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that Intel will be sponsoring AI beginning November 11th through February 7, 2022. We wanted to give you a heads up and walk you through what it will look like.

## How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown in the top right header of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: Intelsponsorship]

## What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

## What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off please report it as a [bug](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug). so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns please leave them as answers below.

Also, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making AI successful.

Comment: Hello Rosie. You write "_Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them._". So, it seems that this would be useful for the sponsor, in this case, Intel, given that, by having their logo (and link to their website) on our site, this would attract more people to their website. You also write "_These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities_", but can you please provide more details? How exactly will this sponsorship help **Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange**?

Comment: I know I already asked you this, but it would be nice to know the answer to this question. We had other sponsors in the past and I didn't notice any improvement e.g. in the number of visitors or the quality of questions or answers (due to these sponsorships), so I am wondering about the utility of these sponsorships for us.